# Remove elements based on other element's value -- XSLT

Tags: xslt, nodes

I have a style-sheet that I am using to remove certain elements based on the value of an other element. However, it is not working ...

Sample Input XML

```
<Model>
<Year>1999</Year>
<Operation>ABC</Operation>
<Text>Testing</Text>
<Status>Ok</Status>
</Model>
```

If Operation value is 'ABC' then remove Text and Status nodes from XML.
And gives the following output.

```
<Model>
<Year>1999</Year>
<Operation>ABC</Operation>
</Model>
```

Here is my style sheet that I am using but it is removing Text and Status nodes from all XMLs even when operation is not 'ABC'.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ID" select="//Operation"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Text | Status">
    <xsl:if test ="$ID ='ABC'">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in Advance

How would I do the same when namespace is present like

```
<ns0:next type="Sale" xmlns:ns0="http://Test.Schemas.Inside_Sales">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is a complete XSLT transformation -- short and simple** (no variables, no `xsl:if`, `xsl:choose`, `xsl:when`, `xsl:otherwise`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "*[Operation='ABC']/Text | *[Operation='ABC']/Status"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Model>
    <Year>1999</Year>
    <Operation>ABC</Operation>
    <Text>Testing</Text>
    <Status>Ok</Status>
</Model>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Model>
   <Year>1999</Year>
   <Operation>ABC</Operation>
</Model>
```

Comment: Thanks for a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks for reminding I forgot to do that. I will fix that. I have another question similar to this one if you can take a look and give me your feedback http://stackoverflow.com/q/10635718/662877

Comment: @JohnXsl: I answered the new question and explained the issue in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Change your `xsl:if` as follows:

```
<xsl:if test="../Operation!='ABC'">
```

and you can get rid of `xsl:variable`.

Answer (score 3):

A better pattern in XSLT than using `<xsl:if>` is to add new templates with match conditions:

```
<xsl:template match="(Text | Status)[../Operation != 'ABC']"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this works:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Model">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Operation[text()!='ABC']">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Year"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Operation"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note that [dradu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1229554/dradu) has a valid answer too