# Remove element based on child element value with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

After reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628311/remove-elements-based-on-other-elements-value-xslt) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635718/xslt-remove-child-element-based-on-parent-child-elements-value) I'm still quit confused how to remove an element (parent) based on another element (child) value. This is the example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Order>
    <Orderline>
        <Itemcode>ABC</Itemcode>
        <Qty>0</Qty>
    </Orderline>
    <Orderline>
        <Itemcode>XYZ</Itemcode>
        <Qty>3</Qty>
    </Orderline>
    <Orderline>
        <Itemcode>DFG</Itemcode>
        <Qty>0</Qty>
    </Orderline>
</Order>
```

This is the XLST I currently have:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "*[Qty='0']/Itemcode | *[Qty='0']/Qty "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces this result:

```
 <Order>
    <Orderline/>
    <Orderline>
        <Itemcode>XYZ</Itemcode>
        <Qty>3</Qty>
    </Orderline>
    <Orderline/>
</Order>
```

How can you remove the empty `<Orderline/>` element as well? The idea is to remove `<Orderline>`, `<Itemcode>` and `<Qty>` elements if value of `Qty = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
<xsl:template match="*[Qty='0']/Itemcode | *[Qty='0']/Qty "/>
```

matches either `Itemcode` or `Qty`, so those are the nodes that end up removed. In order to remove the entire `Orderline` with all its descendants, you only have to do:

```
<xsl:template match="Orderline[Qty='0']"/>
```

Comment: Oooh... of course! I was so focused on the child elements. I tried things like "*Orderline/[Qty='0']" but this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!