# Delete selected repeating node from XML based on another nodes value

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT so please don't mind if I have posted a simple question.
 I have an XML file in which I want to delete some selected repetitive nodes based on value of other nodes.
 I found a partial solution on this link: "[Remove elements based on other element's value -- XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628311/remove-elements-based-on-other-elements-value-xslt)"

I applied the above solution to my XML but it deleted all the tags irrespective of value.
I want to remove all the corresponding SchemeNm Tags for which below tags have the following values :

- Cdtr/Ctry = "US"
- RmtInf/Strd/../CdOrPrtry/Cd = "UK"

It should not remove other SchemeNm Tags for which above condition's are not satisfied.

Input XML:

```
<PmtInf>
    <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <Cdtr>
           <Nm>US</Nm>
           <PstlAdr>
              <Ctry>US</Ctry>
              <AdrLine>ABC</AdrLine>
           </PstlAdr>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
           <Id>
              <Othr>
                 <Id>12345678</Id>
                 <SchmeNm>
                    <Cd>ABCD</Cd>
                 </SchmeNm>
              </Othr>
           </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
        <RmtInf>
            <Strd>
              <CdtrRefInf>
                 <Tp>
                    <CdOrPrtry>
                       <Cd>UK</Cd>
                    </CdOrPrtry>
                 </Tp>
              </CdtrRefInf>
           </Strd>
        </RmtInf>
     </CdtTrfTxInf>
     <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <Cdtr>
           <Nm>US</Nm>
           <PstlAdr>
              <Ctry>DK</Ctry>
              <AdrLine>ABC</AdrLine>
           </PstlAdr>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
           <Id>
              <Othr>
                 <Id>12345678</Id>
                 <SchmeNm>
                    <Cd>ABCD</Cd>
                 </SchmeNm>
              </Othr>
           </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
        <RmtInf>
            <Strd>
              <CdtrRefInf>
                 <Tp>
                    <CdOrPrtry>
                       <Cd>USA</Cd>
                    </CdOrPrtry>
                 </Tp>
              </CdtrRefInf>
           </Strd>
        </RmtInf>
     </CdtTrfTxInf>
  </PmtInf>
```

Expected Output:

```
    <PmtInf>
    <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <Cdtr>
           <Nm>US</Nm>
           <PstlAdr>
              <Ctry>US</Ctry>
              <AdrLine>ABC</AdrLine>
           </PstlAdr>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
           <Id>
              <Othr>
                 <Id>12345678</Id>
              </Othr>
           </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
        <RmtInf>
            <Strd>
              <CdtrRefInf>
                 <Tp>
                    <CdOrPrtry>
                       <Cd>UK</Cd>
                    </CdOrPrtry>
                 </Tp>
              </CdtrRefInf>
           </Strd>
        </RmtInf>
     </CdtTrfTxInf>
     <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <Cdtr>
           <Nm>US</Nm>
           <PstlAdr>
              <Ctry>DK</Ctry>
              <AdrLine>ABC</AdrLine>
           </PstlAdr>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
           <Id>
              <Othr>
                 <Id>12345678</Id>
                 <SchmeNm>
                    <Cd>ABCD</Cd>
                 </SchmeNm>
              </Othr>
           </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
        <RmtInf>
            <Strd>
              <CdtrRefInf>
                 <Tp>
                    <CdOrPrtry>
                       <Cd>USA</Cd>
                    </CdOrPrtry>
                 </Tp>
              </CdtrRefInf>
           </Strd>
        </RmtInf>
     </CdtTrfTxInf>
  </PmtInf>
```

Comment: I think you have forgotten to add your input XML! Also, it would help if you added the XSLT you tried (rather than expect people to follow link), and the output you expect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Start with an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and then match the element(s) you want to remove.

Example:

**XML Input**

```
<PmtInf>
    <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <Cdtr>
            <Nm>US</Nm>
            <PstlAdr>
                <Ctry>US</Ctry>
                <AdrLine>ABC</AdrLine>
            </PstlAdr>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
            <Id>
                <Othr>
                    <Id>12345678</Id>
                    <SchmeNm>
                        <Cd>ABCD</Cd>
                    </SchmeNm>
                </Othr>
            </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
        <RmtInf>
            <Strd>
                <CdtrRefInf>
                    <Tp>
                        <CdOrPrtry>
                            <Cd>UK</Cd>
                        </CdOrPrtry>
                    </Tp>
                </CdtrRefInf>
            </Strd>
        </RmtInf>
    </CdtTrfTxInf>
    <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <Cdtr>
            <Nm>US</Nm>
            <PstlAdr>
                <Ctry>DK</Ctry>
                <AdrLine>ABC</AdrLine>
            </PstlAdr>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
            <Id>
                <Othr>
                    <Id>12345678</Id>
                    <SchmeNm>
                        <Cd>ABCD</Cd>
                    </SchmeNm>
                </Othr>
            </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
        <RmtInf>
            <Strd>
                <CdtrRefInf>
                    <Tp>
                        <CdOrPrtry>
                            <Cd>USA</Cd>
                        </CdOrPrtry>
                    </Tp>
                </CdtrRefInf>
            </Strd>
        </RmtInf>
    </CdtTrfTxInf>
</PmtInf>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CdtTrfTxInf[Cdtr/PstlAdr/Ctry='US' and RmtInf/Strd/CdtrRefInf/Tp/CdOrPrtry/Cd='UK']/CdtrAcct/Id/Othr/SchmeNm"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<PmtInf>
   <CdtTrfTxInf>
      <Cdtr>
         <Nm>US</Nm>
         <PstlAdr>
            <Ctry>US</Ctry>
            <AdrLine>ABC</AdrLine>
         </PstlAdr>
      </Cdtr>
      <CdtrAcct>
         <Id>
            <Othr>
               <Id>12345678</Id>
            </Othr>
         </Id>
      </CdtrAcct>
      <RmtInf>
         <Strd>
            <CdtrRefInf>
               <Tp>
                  <CdOrPrtry>
                     <Cd>UK</Cd>
                  </CdOrPrtry>
               </Tp>
            </CdtrRefInf>
         </Strd>
      </RmtInf>
   </CdtTrfTxInf>
   <CdtTrfTxInf>
      <Cdtr>
         <Nm>US</Nm>
         <PstlAdr>
            <Ctry>DK</Ctry>
            <AdrLine>ABC</AdrLine>
         </PstlAdr>
      </Cdtr>
      <CdtrAcct>
         <Id>
            <Othr>
               <Id>12345678</Id>
               <SchmeNm>
                  <Cd>ABCD</Cd>
               </SchmeNm>
            </Othr>
         </Id>
      </CdtrAcct>
      <RmtInf>
         <Strd>
            <CdtrRefInf>
               <Tp>
                  <CdOrPrtry>
                     <Cd>USA</Cd>
                  </CdOrPrtry>
               </Tp>
            </CdtrRefInf>
         </Strd>
      </RmtInf>
   </CdtTrfTxInf>
</PmtInf>
```